# Javascript Mobile number Specific Mask Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, mobile, mask

I need Regex for mobile number to maintain the international mobile number format but without (00 or +)
which means the first character must be a digit [1-9] and the maxlength should be 15

**Example** 
 
966506863777 is correct, but (+966506863777, 00966506863777) is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is a horrible validation and user experience solution, heck you seem to be the tough coder type. So, here it is:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{0,14}$
```

A javascript validation example:

```
var number = '966506863777';
if (/^[1-9][0-9]{0,14}$/.test(subject)) {
    alert('Valid number');
} else {
    alert('Invalid number');
}
```